# Content-Disposition: inline vs attachment use cases?

Tags: javascript, browser, download, http-headers, content-disposition

I understand that setting `Content-Disposition: inline` allows the browser to preview a downloaded file instead of opening a Save File dialog. I see this as very helpful in most of the cases. How do you then make a decision on when to use `Content-disposition:attachment` ?

I understand from a security point of view, there would be some files that you would not want the browser to execute, like html files. But when considering the same file type, for example, pdf, what kind of scenarios ask for "attachment" vs "inline" , when would you want the user to not preview it but download it directly ?

One use case that comes to mind is that if you are expecting user to download multiple files, probably it makes sense to not open them all for preview and instead just save it to filesystem. I would like to know if there any known/established use cases ?